# Fazer busca em strings na linguagem R

Tags: r

Preciso fazer uma busca numa coluna do df na qual o texto pode não ser exato. Exemplo: `df$titulo=="SE" & df$titulo=="projeto de pesquisa"` não encontra nada. Já tentei usar `like` ao invés de `=`, já tentei usar `df$titulo == "%projeto de pesquisa%"`, mas não funciona. Ah! A função `subset` não traz nada também.

Só para vocês entenderem melhor o que eu estou dizendo, em sql existe um comando like que faz busca em parte da string ao invés do `=`.

Comment: Já tentou `agrep("projeto de pesquisa", df$titulo)`? Veja a página de ajuda da instrução `agrep`, para pesquisas inexatas. Se quer pesquisar por strings alternativas como a pergunta sugere, dê um exemplo da tabela, edite a pergunta com o output de `dput(head(df, 30))`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas a função que você falou me retornou o número das linhas onde tem a string, mas eu quero os registros referentes a esta strings. Exemplo: id_projeto, titulo, orientador, ano, inicio, fim, ... Quando a função encontrar a string, trazer os dados destas colunas em relação a estas linhas.

Comment: @Rui Barradas consegui. Coloquei o parâmetro value=TRUE na função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```
x <- agrep(pattern="projeto de pesquisa", df$titulo, ignore.case = TRUE, 
  value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
```

`ignore.case` ignora maiúsculas e minúsculas e value retorna o valor da string correspondente.

Answer (score 2):

Para um match simples, você pode usar a função `str_subset` do pacote `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
texto <- c("abc projeto de pesquisa cdf", "123 projeto de pesquisa", "progeto de pesquisa")
str_subset(texto, pattern = regex("projeto de pesquisa", ignore_case = T))
```

Note que o terceiro caso, entretanto, que contém um erro de português não é detectado.  O `agrep` que você está usando é mais liberal nesse sentido pois vai fazer um match aproximado, usando a distância de Levenshtein e pode capturar o terceiro caso, se for isso mesmo o que você deseja.